# How to use computed column (case when condition) only in order by clause?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and in my practice I came across this problem. I solved it correctly but have a question. Is there a way that the output does not show the computed column 'RegionTrue'? I just want to see the 3 other columns. TIA

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID,
    CompanyName,
    Region, 
    RegionTrue = 

        CASE
            WHEN Region IS NULL
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
        END
FROM Customers
   ORDER BY
    RegionTrue,
    Region,
    CompanyName
```

Comment: This syntax is non-standard syntax and can mean different things in different databases.  Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to use **( CASE WHEN Region IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)** as order by condition but don't want to show it in select list.

You can simply use the regionTrue condition only in order by clause as below.

```
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, Region    
FROM Customers ORDER BY (CASE
        WHEN Region IS NULL
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
    END), Region, CompanyName
```